# How to remove an html tag in sql column

Tags: sql, mariadb

I want delete h1 tags and text between them from post_content sql column.

I have tried something like this:

```
DELETE FROM wpbz_posts
WHERE `post_content` like '<h1>%</h1>';
```

but don't have a clue, how to work with text between tags, because every text line is different than others.

Any hints or help? Thanks!

Comment: If I read this correctly, you don't want to delete rows, you want to update columns. Look into the REPLACE function: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp

Comment: Oh, missed the bit about needing to remove the text between them as well. What database are you using?

Comment: Please provide sampe input and your expected output.

Comment: Yes exactly! Need to remove whole line <h1>sometext</h1>. I'm using MariaDB

Comment: In MySql 8+ you can do it as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925597/2610061, MariaDB as of 10.0.5 offers something similar: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could UPDATE with a REGEXP_REPLACE to strip the "h1" tags and what's in them

```
UPDATE wpbz_posts 
SET post_content = REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'<h1>.*?</h1>','') 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%</h1>%'
```

The `?` in `.*?` makes it a lazy search, so it only matches till the first `</h1>` that follows the `<h1>` .

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=928fb95213934963c982c68422bda07c)*

There's also an [UPDATEXML](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/updatexml/) function, but that only replaces 1 occurence of a tag.
And will raise an "Incorrect XML value" error if the string doesn't contain a valid XML.

```
UPDATE wpbz_posts 
SET post_content = UpdateXML(post_content,'//h1[1]','') 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%</h1>%'
```